# How to swap arrays based on input integer values in c++?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have following character arrays which corresponds to integer given in front of them.

```
char a[100] = "hi",    //---corresponds to integer 1.
     b[100] = "my",    //                          2.
     c[100] = "name",  //                          3.
     d[100] = "is",    //                          4.
     e[100] = "nis",   //                          5.
     f[100] = "hu";    //                          6.
int x,y;
cin >> x >> y;
```

Suppose each array has some content in it.

Now, i am taking two integer x and y (lies between 1 to 6) as input, and based on x and y, want to swap corresponding arrays.

I don't want to use array of type string. Also i think i can do this using enum, just don't seem to understand how ?

Sample input 1 3

Sample output a=name c=hi

Comment: if there are lots of arrays you might use a std map to associate integers to pointers to those arrays, then do the swap as you want (bitset+xor? just plain memcpy with temporary? You choose)

Comment: Best solution is to use a bi-dimensional array, `arr[6][100]`, or a double pointer `char**` then swap.

Comment: How do you establish the correspondence? And what do you mean by swapping the arrays?

Comment: @Deduplicator: i did not establish the correspondence, all i want if x is 1 and y is 3, content of a go to c and content of c go to a.

Comment: Since you're asking about C++, not just C, I would think you would want to use std::vector, or possibly std::set or std::map, instead of C arrays.  But the question as asked is a bit confusing.  Could you post a sample of the initial contents of the arrays, and the desired result?

Comment: @Nishu it also depends if you want to **copy** the data (the location is somewhat important) or if you can refer to those locations with a pointer. Swapping two pointers is recommended rather than swapping the contents of those arrays.

Comment: @vsoftco : is there any possible solution without using bidimensional array, as i mentioned i don't want to use array of arrays(or array of type string).

Comment: @DanKorn : posted sample input and output

Comment: @Nishu you cannot magically know from `x` and `y` the two arrays among `a b c d e f` at runtime, you need some kind of mapping

Comment: @JBentley: i provided initial contents of array.

Comment: @P0W : can't i do that using enum ?

Comment: `std::map<int, std::string>` is what you need.

Comment: `std::vector<std::string>` is enough if we use offset for index.

Comment: You can swap the contents of two arrays with [`std::swap_ranges`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap_ranges).

Answer (score 2):

You may use the following: (https://ideone.com/N8iQBF)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

bool isValidIndice(int index) { return 1 <= index && index <= 6; }

int main()
{
    char a[100] = "hi",    //---corresponds to integer 1.
        b[100] = "my",     //                          2.
        c[100] = "name",   //                          3.
        d[100] = "is",     //                          4.
        e[100] = "Nis",    //                          5.
        f[100] = "hu";     //                          6.

    char (*mapping[])[100] = {&a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f};

    int x, y;
    std::cin >> x >> y;

    if (isValidIndice(x) && isValidIndice(y)) {
        std::cout << "swap" << std::endl;
        std::swap(*mapping[x - 1], *mapping[y - 1]); // swap the content, so do some copies of char.
    }
    std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << d << " " << e << " " << f << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It would be simpler if you use `std::string`

Answer (score 1):

Finaly doing it using array of string type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
int x,y;  
cout<<"Exchange String\n\n";
string a[6];
a[0]="hi";a[1]="my";a[2]="name";a[3]="is";a[4]="nis";a[5]="hu";
while(1){
cout<<"1) "<<a[0]<<"\n2) "<<a[1]<<"\n3) "<<a[2]<<"\n4) "<<a[3]<<"\n5) "<<a[4]<<"\n6) "<<a[5];
cout<<"\nChoose x and y in between 1 to 6, type -1 to quit" ;
cin>>x >> y;

   if(x==-1){
       exit(1);
   }
   string temp = a[x-1];
   a[x-1] = a[y-1];
   a[y-1]= temp;
 }
}
```

Comment: Note that you may use `a[x - 1].swap(a[y - 1])` to exchange the content instead of doing it manually.